# contentEditable is false only when clicked on the element

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a div and it has some elements inside it. What I want to achieve is when a user double clicks an element inside the div, it sets itself as `contentEditable`. For example: if a user double clicks on a `p` tag, it becomes editable and as soon as he clicks anywhere outside that tag, it sets `contentEditable` to **false**

But what's happening is that when I double click the `p` tag, it does becomes editable but when I click anywhere outside that element, it doesn't set itself to false and it only sets itself to false when I click on the same `p` tag again. Which is very strange. What am I doing wrong here?

**Here's my code:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="zzz">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>this is the text</p>
      <button>click me</button>
      <u>yo</u>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    let arr = [];
    let myiframe = document.getElementById("zzz");

    myiframe.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      obj = e.target;
      arr.push(obj);
      console.log(arr);

      if (arr.length > 2) {
        arr.shift();
      }
      if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
        console.log("same");
      } else {
        console.log("different");
        obj.contentEditable = "false";
      }
      if (event.detail === 2) {
        obj.contentEditable = "true";
        obj.focus();
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI - you don't ever validate the Node type. It doesn't make any sense to make a `<button>` element editable. Additionally, what you have is fine, but it is customary to remove the unwanted _feature_ from all elements (say all `<div>` children) and assign the _feature_ to only the one. This means you don't have to store a cache of the "clicked" elements, you only need to validate that the click one is the correct Node type, then assign the property. It would make all this much easier (and about 15 lines shorter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to store a single element in memory, which is the last editable element. I used `.setAttribute` and got it working

```js
let arr = [];
let myiframe = document.getElementById("zzz");
let activeElement = null
myiframe.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  obj = e.target;
  //console.log(activeElement)
  if (activeElement && activeElement !== obj) {
    activeElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
  }
  if (event.detail === 2) {
    obj.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    activeElement = obj
    obj.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="zzz">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>this is the text</p>
  <button>click me</button>
  <u>yo</u>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `obj.contentEditable = "false";` to `arr[0].contentEditable = "false"` then upon a click it would check if the elements match and if they don't it would disable the elements property.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` is the element you clicked on, so when you click on an element and modify `obj.contentEditable` you’re only ever modifying that element’s `contentEditable` property.